# A static php variable that is assigned only once and never changed

Tags: javascript, php, shopping-cart

the page is online shop page , the user gets js prompt to enter his shopping cart's name, and then selects a product to add to cart, note that each product has its own form and **add to cart** button, the problem is that i want the name of the shopping cart to be static. once the user enters it , it gets stored for all next products he selects, but what happens now is that adding the first product works fine, but the for the second product the shopping cart's name appears to be empty.

JS CODE:

```
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter Cart Name");

    document.getElementById("person").value=person;
    document.getElementById("form").submit();

   // if (person != null) {
   //     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     //   "Your Cart Name is " + person;
    //}


}
```

PHP:

```
 <?php 
    //ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    // error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include('connection.php');

                        if ( isset($_POST['Pro_ID'], $_POST['Price'] , $_POST['Pro_Name'] ) ) {

    static $cart=$_POST['cart_Name'];  //this line is just a try, but it gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE)

                        $qry="INSERT INTO shopping_cart(Cart_Name,Pro_Name,Pro_ID,Price) VALUES ('$cart','".$_POST['Pro_Name']."',".$_POST['Pro_ID'].",".$_POST['Price'].")";
                            $result = mysql_query ($qry );
    $qry = 'SELECT * FROM product' ;
                        }
                    else

                            $qry = 'SELECT * FROM product' ;
                        //Run QUERY
                        $result = mysql_query ($qry);



      ?>
```

for the variable cart_Name, it's been passed as hidden input

Comment: Look at session and use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: but where do i assign cart_name so that it's never changed?

Comment: As @AbraCadaver said in `$_SESSION`... like `$_SESSION['cart_name'] = $_POST['cart_name']`. Then you would just use the session value from there on out.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you do something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_name']) && isset($_POST['cart_name'])) {
   $_SESSION['cart_name'] = $_POST['cart_name'];
}

// then reference $_SESSION['cart_name'] from there on out.
```

Dont forget to call `session_start()` on your page before trying to interact with `$_SESSION`.

Now on the JS side you only want to invoke your prompt if the cart hasnt been named yet. So what I would do is output a var on the page somewhere - needs to be output before any calls to `myFunction()` on the page... id probably put it near the top...:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var cartName = <?php echo isset($_SESSION['cart_name']) 
     ? json_encode($_SESSION['cart_name']) 
     : 'null'; 
   ?>; 
</script>
```

Then in your function you can check it:

```
function myFunction() {
    // note the lack of `var` - this means we are referencing the global namedCart
    // normally i would recommend passing this in as an argument but i dont have enough detail
    // on your set up
    if (namedCart === null) {
      // if named cart doesnt exist we name it from the prompt
      namedCart = prompt("Please enter Cart Name");
    }

    document.getElementById("person").value=namedCart;
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Comment: after putting if (namedCart === null) {, the user prompt never appeared

Comment: what does `console.log(namedCart);` output to your console?

Comment: sorry where do i paste it so i can check what it will output?

Comment: It works, but it only works once. when i try adding another product to the cart nothing gets added to the database

Comment: Well i would need to see your code to debug that... Based on the code that you did provide you should only received the prompt once - and the one occurrence should be if there is no named cart set. After that it should add to existing cart_name. Are you sure you called `$_SESSION`? Are you getting any php errors (check your logs or turn `display_errors` on) is there other code that assumes that you will be setting a new cart name every time?

Comment: you can add the consol.log call to the beginning of `myFunction`.

Comment: is there a way i can show you my whole code? it's 330 lines

Comment: I'm very confused is the problem in the way i used $_SESSION or in the script itself or the php code located above

Answer (score 0):

See php manuel about `session_start()` an $_SESSION[]
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: i assigned $_session["count"] and used it in another php tag but it said that it's undefiend

Comment: $_SESSION (UPPERCASE). Did you first call session_start()? At the beginning of all scripts using the session variable?